# Show physical plan in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When you make a mistake, like selecting a column that doesn't exist, in PySpark's exception message you can see something like this on the bottom:

[image: action data tree]

Is it possible to show this tree normally in PySpark? (without having to cause an exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking at the physical plan. use the `explain` on your sql or dataframe to see that output. find more information on following link

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-explain.html